# Java 8 Streams - Iterator doesn't work like expected

Tags: java, lambda, iterator, java-8

Why does the `.next()` return 7 and not 8 as I would have expected?

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .forEach(i -> intList.add(i));

int value = intList.stream()
            .filter(number -> number == 7)
            .iterator()
            .next();         // returns 7, not 8.
```

Comment: I haven't really had a chance to look at the stream API, but wouldn't filtering using `number -> number == 7` imply that the stream would *only* have `7`s left in it? Can you explain why you expect `8`?

Comment: It was a big misconception on my side. I tried to simplify my problem down to this piece of code above, but at the same time I lost the essence of my actual problem. I guess I have to open another question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter is filtering the stream down to only elements that match the condition `number == 7` (i.e. only a single element, which happens to be the Integer 7), then `next()` returns the first (and only) element. Remember, in order to get the first element from an `Iterator`, you need to call `next()` once.

If you definitely want the first element after the 7 in this ordered list, you can change your filter to `number -> number > 7`.

Comment: Could I somehow get to the 8 if I only know it's predecessor 7 in the underlying List?

Comment: You could use `> 7` or `>= 7`, depending on your needs

Comment: How embarrassing. :-) This makes the function of .filter in conjunction with .iterator a lot more clear to me. Thank you.

Comment: It takes a while to wrap your head around this paradigm, coming from *regular* Java. That's why little test programs like yours are good - they help get your brain "in the mood".

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the issue with the wrong filter predicate pointed out by other answers, using `iterator()` should be your last resort.  This method (and its friend, `spliterator()`) are consisted "escape hatches" for the case where the standard stream methods can't do what you need.

In this case, if you only want the first element, you can call `findFirst()`.  If you want to put the results into an array or collection, use `toArray()` or `collect()`.

Comment: Thanks for these tips. The problem I tried to reduce to the one above, handles a List of `Player`-Objects from whom one gets stored in a `Player::currentPlayer`field. The API provides a getter for the `currentPlayer` that returns a `Player` object and a getter for the player list, that returns the list as a stream. `players.stream()`. After a Player has done his moves, the next one in the list has to be set as the currentPlayer (round robin) and I don't know how to get access to the successor. My only idea was an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually correct because you are filtering your list and only considering elements that satisfy the lambda expression `number -> number == 7`. So only one of the elements in your list gets through.